# Vaadin 8 hiding grid header

Tags: java, grid, vaadin, vaadin8

Is there a way to hide grid header in vaadin 8? It seems there was a method `setHeaderVisible(false)` in Vaadin 7 that made this possible. But I can not find it in Vaadin 8. 
Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the header(s) with [`removeHeaderRow()`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.6/com/vaadin/ui/Grid.html#removeHeaderRow-com.vaadin.ui.components.grid.HeaderRow-)

Full example:

```
// run with `spring run --watch <file>.groovy`
@Grab('com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter:2.0.1')

import com.vaadin.ui.*
import com.vaadin.ui.themes.*
import com.vaadin.shared.*

@groovy.transform.Immutable
class Point {
        BigDecimal x,y
}

@com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI
@com.vaadin.annotations.Theme("valo")
class MyUI extends UI {
        protected void init(com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest request) {
                def g = new Grid<Point>(Point)
                g.items = [new Point(0,0), new Point(1,1)]
                while (g.headerRowCount) {
                        g.removeHeaderRow(0)
                }
                content=g
        }
}
```